# How do I see jQuery errors?

Tags: jquery, error-handling

When an error occurs in jQuery code, IE9, Firefox and Chrome's script debugging tools dont see them - is there a way to make them see jQuery errors?

Comment: Of course they see them - any errors in jQuery are just plain JavaScript errors too. What kind of error are you not seeing at the moment? Doing a `$("#id")` on a non-existant element fails silently for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

The *errors* I was referring to were infact not errors at all e.g. a selector for a non-existent element **does in fact not fail at all**, it simply returns an array with 0 objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you got this, but jQuery is plain javascript.

Every error that **is not caught** by the code will be thrown.

**Wait... caught?**

Yes, you can always avoid throwing errors if you want to manipulate their behaviour. For example, to log it internally or simply give a nicer message to the end user, this is done using, what we call, the **[try-catch block](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp)**.

```
try {
   // you can do some pretty nasty stuff here

   addNumbers(12, 10);
}
catch(err) {
  // now that the error was thrown, you can "catch" it
  //  and play with it, but be nice.

  alert("Ops, there was an error!\n\n" + err);
}
```

You will never see any error on the console with this.

**Back to jQuery**, everything is javascript, so you will see every thrown error right in the console of your favorite browser.